# create File Template sap ui5

Tags: html, sapui5

I am very very new to sap ui5. I try to create a file based on a file template. On creation, a new file is added to my Project and opened within the editor. The file contains source code specified in the Template.
The created file must be .html. My problem first is, how to create this content?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you try to explain a little more what you are trying to do? (I don't mind if you add it in german below your original question, if that is easier for you)

Comment: In SAPUI5 applications you usually have only a single HTML file, which is the entry point. The entire HTML content is dynamically generated.

Comment: Go through this link [OpenUI5 documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) first. Check the Developer Guide, API Reference, Controls. Try as much as you can from this place, then come back with issues that you faced in the code. Because what you have asked is too basic/vague.

Comment: Thanks Breakpoint for the Link. herrlock I will do it the next time  :)